# overriding setDisplayFrame to check set sprite frame

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, frames, ccsprite

How can I override the setDisplayFrame method and check which sprite frame was set, in order to send a message if it matches a particular frame in an animation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override the method to do that, cocos2d 2.x already has this functionality. Look at the code in the `CCAnimation` and `CCAnimationFrame` classes. You can observe for the `CCAnimationFrameDisplayedNotification` in your objects. For an example of this look for `ActionsTest.m` in the cocos2d examples.

Additionally, I strongly suggest that you carefully read [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html) before trying to dig deeper into cocos2d. I think it will clear a lot of your questions. ;-)

Comment: I tried something similar to your suggestion. i got a bit stuck and couldn't get it solved. Here's the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611628/calling-a-method-when-a-particular-ccanimationframe-is-displayed-using-ccanimati)

Comment: @RicardoSánchez-Sáez: I am having the same issue. I checked on the example but didn't really understand how to use `CCAnimationFrameDisplayedNotification` from the example. I would really appreciate some help.